# Reducing 18-0-18 VAC to 12-0-12 VAC

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider

My theory has run away so please bear with me if this is a dumb question.

I have a transformer 18-0-18 V feeding a BR to provide 40ish V to my DC power supply where I need +28 V, +12 V and +5 V. All good so far.

Then I want to power two circuits which run dual rail supplies, one 18-0-18 V, the other 12-0-12 V. I can't run the 12-0-12 V from the 18 V as the two 7812/7912 would be on their limits.

I don't like resistive voltage dividers, and changing the BR on the 12-0-12 V to half-wave will likely introduce too much ripple (it has 1000 µF before the regulators and 220 µF after).

Any suggestion on the best method to achieve this 1/3 voltage reduction?

Comment: But 18VAC rectified into capacitor is only 25 volts. Why can't you use that for 7812 input? How much current is needed from regulators?

Comment: Please draw a circuit showing exactly how these "+28V, +12V and +5V" and "18-0-18 and 12-0-12" supplies are related and where the regulators will be placed.

Comment: ... and also please inform the current requirements for each output DC voltage.

Comment: Which of the outputs need to be operated concurrently? Which share a common ground? Which do *not* need to be regulated - any limits on ripple? To repeat [devnull](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/612639/reducing-18-0-18-to-12-0-12v-ac#comment1615856_612639): What are the currents necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Stop using 7812/7912s. Use a better set of regulators which can provide more current. If necessary, see the regulator data sheets for circuits which use an external transistor to increase current capacity.

Answer (score 0):

I’d use a comparator comparing the capacitor voltage with a reference voltage, controlling a mosfet switch acting as an active rectifier with phase control. The capacitor would be charged up only to the voltage that the regulators require, plus some margin for discharge during the half-cycle between the charging events.

Multiple such pre-regulator circuits would generate the raw voltages you need, followed by linear regulators.

You could connect a large series capacitor or choke to the transformer output to generate a 2nd AC phase, and charge the capacitors 4x per line cycle, decreasing the peak amplitude of charging current. The higher charge pulse frequency is also easier to filter out.

There’s a bit of a devil in the details in such circuits with regards to switching noise suppression. The current slew rate on the switch needs to be controlled (limited), and the switch will necessarily dissipate some switching losses that are higher than the best it could do if driven fast.

Physical design that constrains the switching noise current to flow where it’s of no consequence is also important: the noise must not leak back to the AC line, nor into the DC output. Remember that the 78/79 regulators are quite slow and are quite transparent to wideband AC noise. More modern regulators, or discrete solutions, perform better in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

If your not willing to change the transformer stay with the higher voltage but consider using a few LM317/237/337 series regulators. The standard series can take a 40V input with a 1.5A output.

Also, you won't need to buy a mix of different 78/79 series parts for each separate voltage line, just add two resistors to each circuit to setup the required output voltage.

LM317:
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf?ts=1647693714909&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.fr%252F

LM337:
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm337.pdf?ts=1647737711927&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM337%253Futm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_campaign%253Dapp-null-null-GPN_EN-cpc-pf-google-wwe%2526utm_content%253DLM337%2526ds_k%253DLM337%2BDatasheet%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526gclid%253DEAIaIQobChMIjp-bm73T9gIVAZ2GCh3A6gEvEAAYASAAEgKJQvD_BwE%2526gclsrc%253Daw.ds

For reverence here are two example circuits using a LM317/337 pair, (one actually specifies using an 18v-0-18v transformer). You would just adjust each pot to achieve the voltage output that is needed, or you could replace each pot with a calculated fixed resistor. The second circuit uses a better feedback filtering arrangement to the regulator.

https://blog.circuits4you.com/2015/07/dual-adjustable-dc-power-supply.html

https://www.twovolt.com/power-supply/1-2v-to-37v-adjustable-dual-power-supply-using-lm317-lm337-3/

If your are set on using the 78/79 series parts you could use one set of LM317/337 parts to pre-regulate the rectified voltage down to a more comfortable level.

Comment: excellent, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is to use Buck regulators. They can be gotten small assemblies that will match the pinout of the 7812 etc. Nice part you will not have to change your PCB. You could build them if you like but they are maybe a buck or two in volume. The efficiency is high the heat will be way less.

Comment: thanks, will look into this idea